# What is the Big O notation for RSA encryption?

Tags: time-complexity, rsa, big-o

I'm doing a task on RSA encryption, and I'm wondering what the big O notation for the entire RSA algorithm is, i.e. Generating keys, encrypting a message, and then decrypting that message, if it is possible to figure that out. How would you go about figuring that out?

Thanks in advance

Comment: From a little bit googling I would say it is equivalent with "exponention by squaring" algorithm complexity, which depends on your provided hardware a lot.Also have a look at https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6164/how-do-i-derive-the-time-complexity-of-encryption-and-decryption-based-on-modula#:~:text=With%20standard%20RSA%20assumptions%2C%20computing,(log(N)).

Comment: Most software for generating "typically"-sized RSA primes use hybrid techniques that are dominated by the cost of miller-rabin probabilistic primality tests whose complexity is [explained here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Generation_of_probable_primes), although the explanation talks about using FFT multiplication which is **not** used for typically-sized RSA primes, but you can combine the analysis of multiplication in the link provided by the comment above with the analysis in the wikipedia article.

Comment: Big O is a measure of how the size of the input impacts the computation time. So to clarify - are you asking for BigO of RSA encryption wrt increasing the size of the key? Or the size of the plaintext?

Comment: I'm asking for the BigO of RSA with an increasing key size yes, I've seen people saying that it can be simplified to O(n^3). Does that sound correct?